# How to say where I was born

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> This is Delhi that I was born in.

&

> This is Delhi where I was born in.

Are both of these sentences right? If not, what is the right way to say this?

Comment: I would say "I was born in Delhi".

Answer (score 3):

The "in" at the end of both sounds odd and some people (following advice from their grade school English teacher) would say incorrect, as it is a preposition at the end of the sentence.

But more importantly, to make them more standard English I'd rewrite as:

- This is Delhi where I was born.
- This is Delhi in which I was born. (or "Delhi that I was born in")

In other words, the "where" implies an "in" somewhere. You don't have to say it (though your meaning was clear): it's implied that you were born IN that city.

Comment: Where you say "This is Delhi where I was born," it should read, "This is Delhi, where I was born." Note the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @fool4jesus that the *in* at the end of each version sounds wrong. You should include a comma after the word *Delhi* because what follows is a non-restrictive appositive.* This is how I would phrase the statement:

> This is Delhi, where I was born.

OR

> This is Delhi, the place in which I was born.

* See [Wikipedia's article on apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) - in particular, this very similar example:

> > "I visited Canada, a beautiful country – The appositive (that it is beautiful) is not needed to identify Canada."

Also note:

> > "In English, non-restrictive appositives are typically set off by commas."